# How to override base url of joomla

Tags: joomla, root, radix

I want to override the root Url of a Joomla site. JURI::base(true) is the 
problem because it returns / . How can I change this?

http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/root lets me override the root, but components like
the breadcrumb and logout use something else, probably JURI::base().

thanks

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you want to redirect all traffic from one domain to another?

Comment: Could you explain, why do you want to do that and whats your final goal?

Comment: Try the `$live_site` parameter in the configuration.php file

Comment: I am using Joomla inside an IFrame, so links that go to '/' end up as a nested frame. Breadcrumbs, logouts etc go to this link, so it needs to be overridden in Joomla. Thanks for not telling me to avoid IFrames.

Comment: Sorry Lodder, it just changes the domain name, not the path on the site.